# Translate Ajax JSON messages with POEdit

Tags: ajax, json, poedit

The website is correctly translated using `_("foo")` to make POEdit translate them. The problem is that I have `json_encode()` method, that I use to show messages in a form.

I'm using it like this:

```
echo json_encode(array('info' => 'error', 'msg' => _("Message here")));`
```

And although POEdit does find the text, it does not translate.

Does someone know how I can translate these messages using POEdit, or any other way? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

“Poedit” doesn’t translate things at runtime, your gettext library does. You need to initialize it and actually *load* the MO file with translations. Consult the documentation for whatever language/runtime this is (e.g. plain PHP and WordPress would do it differently).